# GenericForeignKey violation ONLY when User model given, Postgres

Tags: django, django-models

I have an activity app to log user or anything activity actions. So to implement this i had to use GenericForeignKeys on my model since a number of models could perform actions.

Here's my model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    actor_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType, related_name='actor'
    )
    actor_object_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    actor = generic.GenericForeignKey(
        ct_field='actor_content_type', fk_field='actor_object_id'
    )
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I can create records fine, passing any model instance into 'actor', but when I pass a django User model instance I get the following error:

```
self = <django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x2d3bfd0>

    def _commit(self):
        if self.connection is not None:
            try:
>               return self.connection.commit()
E               IntegrityError: insert or update on table "auth_permission" violates foreign key constraint "content_type_id_refs_id_d043b34a"
E               DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(3) is not present in table "django_content_type".

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py:240: IntegrityError
>
```

Can anyone figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your settings module, change the ordering of your 'INSTALLED_APPS' variable so that 'django.contrib.auth' is below 'django.contrib.contenttypes', e.g.:

From:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    ...etc
)
```

To:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...etc
)
```